# Spring boot static resources and controllers endpoint mixed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an endpoint 'localhost:8080/users' and a controller which should redirect any reqest which match '/users/**' pattern to 'localhost:8080/users' and show login page by returning index.html file which is an entry point for angular application. I have also a static resources in directory '..resources/static/users' which contains built angular applications. The index.html file is look as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href="/users/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
</head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="runtime-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="vendor-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="vendor-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="main-es2015.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
</html>
```

The problem is that any request for static js files match my controller endpoint pattern and return the index.html file. How to resolve such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ResourceResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/reactive/resource/ResourceResolver.html) for resolving static resources.

From [*Static Resources* section in *Spring Framework Reference*](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-static-resources):

> Given a request that starts with `/resources`, the relative path is
>   used to find and serve static resources relative to `/public` under
>   the web application root or on the classpath under `/static`.
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableWebMvc
> public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
>
>     @Override
>     public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
>         registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
>             .addResourceLocations("/public", "classpath:/static/")
>             .setCachePeriod(31556926);
>     }
> }
> ```

And,

> [WebJars](https://www.webjars.org/documentation) are also supported through the `WebJarsResourceResolver` which
>   is automatically registered when the `org.webjars:webjars-locator-core`
>   library is present on the classpath.